# Force sbt 0.11 to run tests

Tags: sbt

How can I force `sbt` 0.11 to fail when doing `package` or `publish` unless all the tests pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `build.sbt`, add:

```
publish <<= publish dependsOn (test in Test)
```

(or the equivalent for `package`)

Comment: To make this work with xsbt-web-plugin one has to use a little more verbose solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547784/sbt-package-depend-on-test