# SBT "package" depend on "test"

Tags: sbt, lift, xsbt-web-plugin

How do I make target "package" depend on target "test" ?

There is a solution here: [Force sbt 0.11 to run tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277009/force-sbt-0-11-to-run-tests)
But it doesn't really work with the xsbt-web-plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
Keys.`package` <<= (test in Test, Keys.`package` in Compile) map { (_, in) =>
  println("after package & test")
  in
}
```

It runs test, and iff the tests were successful, runs package task. (tested on fresh install of lift-2.5-RC2)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solves the problem.
BTW, looking at the solution I fount a shorter version that works too:

    Keys.`package` <<= (Keys.`package` in Compile) dependsOn (test in Test)