# Idiomatic use of sbt to release (tested) artifacts

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to use sbt to publish my project.

I'm used to maven, and need some help (mentally) transitioning.

By default I see 'publish' depends on 'package', but 'package' does not depend on 'test'. Of course I only want to publish tested code. How should I ensure this?

Of course I could [make package depend on test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547784/sbt-package-depend-on-test), but the fact that this is not the default sort of suggests this is not idiomatic use of sbt. What would be the 'right' way to achieve this?

How do I find out more about best practices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am always running `sbt clean test publish-local publish` (or `publish-signed`). This ensures any error that occurs before `publish` halts the process.

Another possibility would be to use the [sbt-release plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release). This runs tests and also watches and adjusts your version strings.

Comment: Thanks! Orchestrating this independently of the task dependencies with a tool like the sbt-release plugin indeed seems like a nice way to achieve this. Doesn't really protect us against people accidentally publishing without testing, but there's a trade-off there I suppose.