# How to disable running tests in sbt publishLocal

Tags: scala, sbt

How do we disable running tests for `sbt publishLocal` ?

To disable running tests in assembly the following has been suggested (though I have seen it not working as well..):

```
sbt 'set test in assembly := {}' assembly
```

What about for `publishLocal` ?  The following have all been attempted .. yet the tests always are run:

```
sbt 'set test in publish := {}' publishLocal

sbt 'set test in publishLocal := {}' publishLocal

sbt 'set test in assembly := {}' publishLocal
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your entire `build.sbt` file? Tests don't run by default before publishing.

Comment: @eric I did not know that tests do not run by default before publishing. My company has a custom build plugin - maybe that is the cause. will look into it.

Comment: Hope that helps steer you in the right direction. Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277009/force-sbt-0-11-to-run-tests) for a clue as to what you might want to look for: `publishLocal << publishLocal dependsOn (test in Test)`.